# gorilla mux excluding request by extension

Tags: go, gorilla

An attempt to configure go server routing with `github.com/gorilla/mux` to respond to all requests with index.html but exclude requests with extension .jpg|.js|.png

Static files excluded due to extension will be routed to FileServer. configured.

**Failed Attempt**

```
  func main() {
        r := mux.NewRouter()

        r.HandleFunc("/{path:^.*([!js|jpg|png|gif])$}", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            http.ServeFile(w, r, "dist/index.html")
        })

        r.PathPrefix("/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("dist"))))

        http.Handle("/", r)
        http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Better approach welcome, hoped to use regular expression so things where left intact with no crazy if/else conditions

```
func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()

    r.HandleFunc("/{path:.*}", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if HasSuffix(r.URL.Path, []string{"js", "css", "gif", "jpeg", "woff2", "woff", "ttf"}) == false {
            fmt.Println("serving index")
            http.ServeFile(w, r, "dist/index.html")
        } else {
            http.ServeFile(w, r, "dist/"+r.URL.Path)
        }
    })

    //r.PathPrefix("/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("dist"))))

    http.Handle("/", r)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}

//HasSuffix check if url has suffix
func HasSuffix(path string, parts []string) bool {
    for _, part := range parts {
        fmt.Println("checking if part:" + part + " exists in path:" + path)
        if strings.HasSuffix(path, part) == true {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This `"^.*([!js|jpg|png|gif])$}"` is not a valid regular expession for matching string that does not have  .jpg|.js|.png

However, In golang *Negative lookahead* isn't supported for technical reasons, specifically because it conflicts with the O(n)-time guarantees of the library.

I would suggest you to do it other way around ie, add handlers for png,js,css files etc to serve the files as such